# How can I write my data (which contains floats) to a txt file in python

Tags: python, text

I have a code that brings data from a text file, calculates some things with the data and then prints the answers. Now, I want to write the answers to a text file. The answers contain floats. That is, it looks like this

2360108302.9038

23459458290.8902

etc

Here is what I am writing:

```
print(si)
with open('s.txt', 'a') as fd:                 
    fd.writelines(si)
```

I get the error:

288731.39149741945
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read.py", line 57, in 
    fd.writelines(inv_mass)
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

It just prints one answer and then I get the error.
So, how can I fix the problem so that whatever I am printing gets saved in a text file?

Thank you

Comment: try this: fd.writelines(str(si))

Comment: Yes, I tried that but my data gets all squished together with no spaces and I can't see the data points separately as how the print function outputs the data

Comment: I have added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for writing in file float need to converted in string and newline needed to write line by line. here is a example of writing floats:

```
sd = [1.34, 45.5768] . # list of floats
with open('fileName.txt', 'a') as fd:
    for d in sd:
        fd.writelines(str(d))
        fd.writelines("\n")
```

output:

```
1.34
45.5768
```

in your code you can modify like this:

```
    fd.writelines(str(si))
    fd.writelines("\n")
```

Comment: Ok, that almost works. But it writes the squished data and then it writes the data in its own line like how you show it in your output. How can I make it write only the data in new lines  as shown in your output without this part above it: 1.34 45.5768

Comment: I got it I just added another fd.writelines("\n") before fd.writelines(str(si)). Thanks for your help.